# Typesafe config: write / create reference

Tags: java, scala, config, typesafe-config, pureconfig

What I want to do is quite straight forward. I want to create a config object in my code and some of the values should be references. I then want to save that config to a file and later, when reading it, the references will be substituted with the correct value. 
I use [lightbends typesafe config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library and the scala wrapper [pureconfig](http://%20https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) (but don't mind about pureconfig)

Now to read and substitute values correctly the config needs to look something like this:

```
"name" {
    "someNormalValue" : "v"
    "subsitute" : ${substitute-value}        
}
```

The question is, how can I actually generate such a config using the mentioned library.

Ps. I'm looking for a nicer solution than just rendering the config and going back to 'manually' remove the double quotes around `${substitute-value}`

Thanks for you responses!